# Using Comparator in an object

Tags: java, collections, comparator

I have a class named `Age` which has the attributes `Years`, `months` and `days`.

I also have a list of `Age` instances. I would like to find the maximum age from that list. To do so I would like to use the `Comparator` class.

Any help would appreciated.

Comment: Please read : [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Compare the year, and then the month if the same and then the day if the same, just as you would do in real life.

Comment: You will need to provide us with code as well as what you have tried.

Comment: can you tell us what have you tried till now?

Comment: provide the field as a reflection field and apply comparator on them. you might get the code on internet

Comment: @AniketKulkarni thanks for the comment. You should have ignored the uestion if u did not understand.

Comment: Actually, no. It is important to ask questions in an understandable way and this question was difficult to understand until I edited it. Therefore @AniketKulkarni has a valid point.

Comment: @blalasaadri : Thanks. Yeah it was bit more difficult to understand the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can write a comparator which would look something like this:

```
Comparator<Age> ageComparator = new Comparator<Age>() {
    @Override
    public int compare(Age age1, Age age2) {
        if(age1.getYear() != age2.getYear()) {
            return age1.getYear() < age2.getYear() ? -1 : 1;
        } else if(age1.getMonth() != age2.getMonth()) {
            return age1.getMonth() < age2.getMonth() ? -1 : 1;
        } else if(age1.getDay() != age2.getDay()) {
            return age1.getDay() < age2.getDay() ? -1 : 1;
        } else {
            return 0;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Would the downvoter care to explain?

Comment: @SukritKalia Glad to hear it. :) Could you then mark this answer as accepted?

Comment: i am not eligible to vote up as i do not have 15 votes. I would have been glad to mark your answer as EXCELLENT.

Comment: @SukritKalia You don't have to vote up to accept an answer. Under the voting buttons there's a check symbol which you can choose to accept this answer as correct.

Comment: @blalasaadri, lol )))

Answer (score 1):

If U would like to make for each field his own `Comparator` do like this

```
public static Comparator<Age> yearComparator = new Comparator<Age>() {
        @Override
        public int compare(Age age1, Age age2) {
            return age1.getYear() - age2.getYear();
        }
    };
```

And then

```
Arrays.sort(yourAgesArray, Age.yearComparator);
```

Or

```
Collections.sort(yourAgesArray, Age.yearComparator);
```

Read this [article](http://www.journaldev.com/780/java-comparable-and-comparator-example-to-sort-objects) to understand this better.

Comment: Why have separate comparators? You could compare years, months and days in one comparator quite easily.

Comment: Better from Java8 : `public static Comparator<Age> yearComparator = Comparator.comparing(Age::getYear);`

Answer (score 0):

You should probably implement the [`Comparable`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html) interface in your Age class. However, you should maybe consider using a 3rd party time handling library or use the one from java.time (depending on which version of Java are you using). Comparing time can sometimes get messy.

When your class implements the `Comparable` interface you can use the [`Arrays.sort()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#sort(java.lang.Object[])) method from the platform.

Answer (score 0):

From Java 8, you can use this one-line solution :

```
Age maxAge = collection
  .stream()
  .max(
     Comparator.comparing(Age::getYear)
    .thenComparing(Age::getMonth)
    .thenComparing(Age::getDay)
  )
  .get();
```